# Python Beautiful Soup modify onclick Event Attribute

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to modify the behavior of a button from my .html page, more precisely I have:

```
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next">
```

And I want to obtain:

```
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit"  value="NEXT" Onclick="window.location.href='http://www.some_web_page.com/'">
```

It is possible to do this using bs4? Until now I managed to identify, the desired part f the html page, but I am not sure how can I make changes now:

```
page=requests.get('https://www.some_page.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print (soup.findAll(id="next"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [44]: html = '''<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next">'''

In [45]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

In [46]: soup.input['Onclick'] = "window.location.href='http://www.some_web_page.com/'"

In [47]: soup
Out[47]: <html><body><input Onclick="window.location.href='http://www.some_web_page.com/'" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" id="next" name="signIn" type="submit" value="Next"/></body></html>
```